# Connect to networked mysql docker container with local client

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have just followed a tutorial on using Docker. I started with installing different containers and when I got to mysql, i installed it by running

```
docker container run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 mysql
```

After the container has been created, I have been able to connect to MySQL with Heidi, by using 127.0.0.1, root and 123456 as password.
I eventually moved forward with another tutorial on installing WordPress with docker.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYhLEV-sRpY

The yaml for setting up the containers is bellow. Everything works just fine, but when it comes to connecting to the database using Heidi, I just do not get what to do - what connection data to use or what to change in the yaml to be able to connect from local machine.

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: You can try creating a Network inside the docker and then running both Mysql and Heidi in the same network using --network flag

Comment: @TusharJajodia Docker Compose [creates a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should expose 3306 port to local machine.  Then, you can connect to MySQL by using `host=127.0.0.1`.

Update the yaml file like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  ...
```